# Xcode & Git and build directory problems

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I have been using Xcode and Git on this project for about 3 months now and never had to ignore my build files.  If I look in my other projects, there is not /build directory.  Today, I checked out someone else's workspace and made my changes.  When I go to GitHub, I see all these files I do not want included in my checkin.  I also see in Finder a /build folder in my project.  I have been using the default Xcode/DerivedData/.…. folder and cannot find anywhere that would have changed.  Any ideas?

**Could it be because this new project is in a Workspace?**

Comment: Can't you just add what you don't want to .gitignore?

Comment: Look at your history. It is relatively easy to modify your last commit with `git commit --amend` http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things

Comment: Yes, I can use gitignore, but that's not the point.  What setting might be placing my /build folder in my project?  I had been using the default settings and never got the /build folder in my project.  Suddenly today something has gone awry!  Thank you for your help.